# VueJS dragging an element on occasion causes it to stick to the mouse pointer

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a div (which holds a Zoom iFrame) which I would like to move around the screen. However... on occasion if the user is being jerky with the mouse, it sticks to the pointer and the only way you can fix that is by refreshing the page.

Is that something anyone else has experienced and how did you solve it?

I would imagine its something to do with my Javascript portion and how I am listening for some events.

EDIT: Wanted to add that the below code was basically adjusted for Vue from this article: https://javascript.info/mouse-drag-and-drop

Thanks in advance!

HTML:

```
<div
  class="zoom-wrapper"
  ref="draggableContainer"
>
  <div
    @mousedown="dragMouseDown"
    ref="grabBar"
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
 dragMouseDown(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                const { draggableContainer, grabBar } = this.$refs;

                let shiftX = event.clientX - draggableContainer.getBoundingClientRect().left;
                let shiftY = event.clientY - draggableContainer.getBoundingClientRect().top;

                draggableContainer.style.position = 'absolute';
                draggableContainer.style.zIndex = 1000;

                moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);

                function moveAt(pageX, pageY) {
                    draggableContainer.style.left = pageX - shiftX + 'px';
                    draggableContainer.style.top = pageY - shiftY + 'px';
                }

                function onMouseMove(event) {
                    moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);
                }

                window.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);

                window.onmouseup = function () {
                    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
                    grabBar.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.dragMouseDown);
                    window.onmouseup = null;
                };
            },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a working demo to move the element via click.

I think currently your mistake is how you wanted to remove the eventlistener on `mousedown`

I hope this demo will give you a hint how to solve your problem.

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    let draggableContainer = ref(null)
    
    function mousedown (e) {
      window.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemove)
      window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseup)

      let prevX = e.clientX
      let prevY = e.clientY

      function mousemove (e) {
        // new x - where is the mouse now
        const newX = prevX - e.clientX
        const newY = prevY - e.clientY

        const rect = draggableContainer.value.getBoundingClientRect()
        draggableContainer.value.style.left = rect.left - newX + 'px'
        draggableContainer.value.style.top = rect.top - newY + 'px'

        prevX = e.clientX
        prevY = e.clientY
      }
      function mouseup () { // remove event listener
        window.removeEventListener('mousemove', mousemove)
        window.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseup)
      }
    }

    return {
      draggableContainer,
      mousedown
    }
  }
});
app.mount("#demo");
```

```css
.zoom-wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #111;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div id="demo">
  <div
    class="zoom-wrapper"
    ref="draggableContainer"
    @mousedown="mousedown"
  >
   insert iframe
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You got a very similar solution to what I ended up using. Therfore +10